# Salesforce Site.login returns null when used in a REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, salesforce

I am trying to write a custom login screen for a portal user in react JS. I had a controller exposed as a rest API which is using SIte.login(username, password, url) for the user credential validation. But I was, always, getting null from Site.login call. I am using below code.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/my_login/*')
global class My_custom_SiteRegisterController {
    public static final String USERNAME = 'username';
    public static final String PASSWORD = 'password';

    /**
     * Response body
     */
    global class MyLoginResponse {
        Boolean success {get; set;}
        Integer statusCode {get; set;}
        String uusername {get; set;}
        String ppassword {get; set;}
    }

    @HttpGet
    global static void login() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String username = req.params.get(USERNAME);
        String password = req.params.get(PASSWORD);

        PageReference pr = Site.login(username, password, '/apex/home');
        if(pr != null){
            createRestResponse(200,true,username,password);
        }else{
            createRestResponse(200,false,username,password);
        }

        return;
    }

    private static void createRestResponse(Integer statusCode, Boolean success,String username,string password) {
        MyLoginResponse my_Login_Response = new MyLoginResponse();
        my_Login_Response.statusCode = statusCode;
        my_Login_Response.success = success;
        my_Login_Response.uusername = username;
        my_Login_Response.ppassword = password;

        RestResponse res =  RestContext.response;
        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        res.statusCode = my_Login_Response.statusCode;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(my_Login_Response));
        RestContext.response = res;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return null if the Login failed to login.   Use a `Try` `Catch` , and catch for null to handle the correct REST response.